# How to map values from a database to a view model in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orm, viewmodel

I am having trouble with what should be a very simple task. I'm trying to map values retrieved from a database to a view model. I then want to pass that as the model to my view.

The view model is called EditAdminModelVM and it contains a smaller subset of properties from a larger class called UserProfile. I chose to use a view model because I do not want the user to be able to update the whole domain model, only a few from it.

Here is the ViewModel:

```
public class EditAdminModelVM
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.")]
    [Display(Name = "First name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.")]
    [Display(Name = "Last name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(250)]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    //[Remote("doesUserNameExist", "Account", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "Username already exists. Please enter a different User Name.")] //note this checks from client-side only - server side check is built in to membership
    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the controller 9though it does not work):

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public ActionResult EditAdmin(int id = 0)
    {
        PpDB db = new PpDB();

        var viewModel = new EditAdminModelVM();

        viewModel = db.UserProfiles
             .Where(x => x.UserId == id)
             .Select(x => new EditAdminModelVM
             {
                 FirstName = x.FirstName,
                 LastName = x.LastName,
                 Email = x.Email,
                 UserName = x.UserName
             });

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

In this case the .Select is underlined with a squiggle which says something about IQueryable. But if I try to set var viewModel = new IQueryable; I get another error.

I suppose this could be a syntax problem. This DB query should only return one row so I did not think IQueryable is necessary, but I am no expert.

If you could please provide me with a working a sample of how to construct this code block, then I could learn by example - better for my tired brain.

Much appreciated!

**UPDATE FOR KEN**
Here is the updated controller:

```
 [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public ActionResult EditAdmin(int id = 0)
    {
        PpDB db = new PpDB();

        List<EditAdminModelVM> viewModel = new List<EditAdminModelVM>();

        viewModel = db.UserProfiles
             .Where(x => x.UserId == id)
             .Select(x => new EditAdminModelVM
             {
                 FirstName = x.FirstName,
                 LastName = x.LastName,
                 Email = x.Email,
                 UserName = x.UserName,
                 UserId = x.UserId
             }).ToList();

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

And here is the view:

```
@model List<PpModels.Models.EditAdminModelVM>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit Admin";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>UserProfile</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserId)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: You don't need to reassign values to model. You will get model values in your ActionResult Method parameter. Just assign these model values to db object and do code to update your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `var viewModel = new EditAdminModelVM();` to `List<EditAdminModelVM> viewModel = new List<EditAdminModelVM>();` and append `ToList()` to the end of `db.UserProfiles` query. Now, this wiil pass  collection of EditAdminModelVM to your view. Iterate through this collection in your view to get desired output.

**Update:** For single instance:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult EditAdmin(int id = 0)
{
    PpDB db = new PpDB();

    var viewModel = new EditAdminModelVM();

    viewModel = db.UserProfiles
         .Where(x => x.UserId == id)
         .Select(x => new EditAdminModelVM
         {
             FirstName = x.FirstName,
             LastName = x.LastName,
             Email = x.Email,
             UserName = x.UserName
         }).FirstOrDefault();

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

For this you don't need to iterate in your view:

Use `@model ProofPixModels.Models.EditAdminModelVM` in your view.

Comment: Thanks so much! I tried that and now get the following error in my view: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[PpModels.Models.EditAdminModelVM]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'PpModels.Models.EditAdminModelVM'. This is the declaration at the top of the view: @model PpModels.Models.EditAdminModelVM. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok. I got around that error by declaring the following instead: @model IEnumerable<ProofPixModels.Models.EditAdminModelVM> at the top of my view. I then wrapped my form fields in a foreach loop. Since this view is suposed to show only a single instance of the view model, am I perhaps going about this the wrong way still? It seems counterintuitive to wrap this in a foreach loop? Thanks for the help!

Comment: In your view use `@model List<EditAdminModelVM>()` as your model

Comment: Thanks. I am now getting the following error when loading the view: Compilation Error: System.Collections.Generic.List<PpModels.Models.EditAdminModelVM>' does not contain a definition for 'UserId' and no extension method 'UserId' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<PpModels.Models.EditAdminModelVM>

Comment: please update your controller method and show what are you doing in view in your original question. So, that I can look and rectify.

Comment: Awesome you Rock! Thank you so much. If you don't mind, when I post the form back to the controller, do I have to assign the form values to the model before saving the changes in the db? Again I only want to update a subset of the domain model's fields. Thanks again!